# Is there a way to Delete/Update existing alias in ElasticSearch using java high level client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there a way to delete/update the existing alias(not index, just alias) using Java High level rest client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what version of Elasticsearch you are using but I found something like that: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-update-aliases.html

Example:

```
IndicesAliasesRequest request = new IndicesAliasesRequest();
AliasActions removeAction =
    new AliasActions(AliasActions.Type.REMOVE)
    .index("index3")
    .alias("alias3");
request.addAliasAction(removeAction);
```

Comment: This version is not yet released.

Answer (score 0):

Since ES 7.6 you can do:

```
DeleteAliasRequest request = new DeleteAliasRequest("index1", "alias1");
```